# Stopwatch function in R

Tags: matlab, r

Is there an R timer or stopwatch function similar to MATLAB's [tic/toc](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/tic.html)?

Comment: for what it's worth, googling `[r] tic toc` now (Feb 2013) gives lots of answers; don't know if it did back in Nov 2011 or not ...

Answer (score 39):

There are plenty of profiling tools in R, as Dirk mentioned.  If you want the simplicity of tic/toc, then you can do it in R too.

EDIT: I've cannibalised the garbage collection functionality from the MATLAB package, and `tic` now lets you choose whether you are interested in total elapsed time or just the user time.

```
tic <- function(gcFirst = TRUE, type=c("elapsed", "user.self", "sys.self"))
{
   type <- match.arg(type)
   assign(".type", type, envir=baseenv())
   if(gcFirst) gc(FALSE)
   tic <- proc.time()[type]         
   assign(".tic", tic, envir=baseenv())
   invisible(tic)
}

toc <- function()
{
   type <- get(".type", envir=baseenv())
   toc <- proc.time()[type]
   tic <- get(".tic", envir=baseenv())
   print(toc - tic)
   invisible(toc)
}
```

Usage is, e.g., `tic(); invisible(qr(matrix(runif(1e6), nrow=1e3))); toc()`

Answer (score 14):

There is a MATLAB emulation package *[matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlab/index.html)* on CRAN. It has implementations of `tic` and `toc` (but they look very similar to the functions in Richie Cottons answer; "elapsed" is used instead of "user.self" in `proc.time()`)

```
> tic
function (gcFirst = FALSE) 
{
    if (gcFirst == TRUE) {
        gc(verbose = FALSE)
    }
    assign("savedTime", proc.time()[3], envir = .MatlabNamespaceEnv)
    invisible()
}
<environment: namespace:matlab>
> toc
function (echo = TRUE) 
{
    prevTime <- get("savedTime", envir = .MatlabNamespaceEnv)
    diffTimeSecs <- proc.time()[3] - prevTime
    if (echo) {
        cat(sprintf("elapsed time is %f seconds", diffTimeSecs), 
            "\n")
        return(invisible())
    }
    else {
        return(diffTimeSecs)
    }
}
<environment: namespace:matlab>
```

Answer (score 9):

A very simple equivalence with tic and toc that you could have:

```
tic=proc.time()[3]

...code...

toc=proc.time()[3] - tic
```

Where the [3] is because we are interested in the third element in the vector returned by proc.time(), which is elapsed time.

Answer (score 8):

Direct equivalents of tic and toc do not exist.

Please see `help(system.time)` as well as the R Extensions manual about profiling.  Discussions of profiling and profiling tools is also in the 'Intro to HPC with R' slides referenced on the [High Performance Computing with R taskview](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)

Answer (score 6):

## A Closure Approach

A very clean and simple way to do this is by using a closure (which just means having a function within a function):

```r
tic <- function () { 
    now <- proc.time()
    function () { 
        proc.time() - now 
    }
}
```

You start the timer like so:

```r
toc <- tic()
```

And then you get the time back like this:

```r
toc()
```

Which outputs a named vector that gets printed like so:

```r
 user  system elapsed 
0.008   0.004   2.055
```

Even with the simplicity of this version you also get all the functionality of the Matlab and Richie Cotton's versions plus the added feature of being able to run multiple timers:

```r
toc1 <- tic()
toc2 <- tic()
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a relatively new package tictoc that replicates the features exactly as you would use them in Matlab.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tictoc/index.html

```
## Basic use case
tic()
print("Do something...")
Sys.sleep(1)
toc()
# 1.034 sec elapsed
```

Answer (score 2):

As of the date 2015-03-25,
and possibly earlier,
the [pracma](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/index.html)
package contains the functions `tic()` and `toc()`.

Example:

```
> library(pracma)
> tic()
> for(i in 1:10000) mad(runif(10000))    # kill time
> toc()
elapsed time is 18.610000 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but here is a one line solution.

```
time.it<-function(f) { a<-proc.time(); out<-f(); print(proc.time()-a); out }
```

And an example for usage:

```
result<-time.it(function(){ A<-matrix(runif(5000^2),nrow=5000); b<-runif(5000); solve(A,b) } )
user  system elapsed 
12.788  12.268   8.623
```

Otherwise, [microbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html) is my favorite in terms of packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: you can actually 'simulate' tic
and toc in R, so that you can write

```
tic
## do something
toc
```

without parentheses. The trick is to abuse the `print`
function, as demonstrated in [Fun: tic and toc in R](http://enricoschumann.net/R/tictoc.htm):

```
tic <- 1
class(tic) <- "tic"

toc <- 1
class(toc) <- "toc"

print.tic <- function(x, ...) {
    if (!exists("proc.time"))
        stop("cannot measure time")
    gc(FALSE)
    assign(".temp.tictime", proc.time(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

print.toc <- function(x,...) {
    if (!exists(".temp.tictime", envir = .GlobalEnv))
        stop("did you tic?")
    time <- get(".temp.tictime", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    rm(".temp.tictime", envir = .GlobalEnv)
    print(res <- structure(proc.time() - time,
                           class = "proc_time"), ...)
    invisible(res)
}
```

So typing

```
tic
Sys.sleep(2)
toc
```

should results in something like this:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   2.002
```

As I said, it's a trick; `system.time`, `Rprof` and
packages such as [`rbenchmark`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rbenchmark) are the way to measure
computing time in R.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link**, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("tictoc")
library(tictoc)
# Timing nested code. 
# The string provided in the call to tic() becomes a prefix to the output of toc()
tic("outer")
    Sys.sleep(1)
    tic("middle")
        Sys.sleep(2)
        tic("inner")
            Sys.sleep(3)
        toc() # inner
# inner: 3.004 sec elapsed
    toc() # middle
# middle: 5.008 sec elapsed
toc() # outer
# outer: 6.016 sec elapsed
```

The [tictoc](http://jabiru.github.io/tictoc/) package implements the functionality described by previous answers - thank you for inspiration! The package also adds nested timing, collecting the timings in user-defined variables, custom messages and callbacks.