# Program for Armstrong number in r

Tags: r

[Armstrong Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) are numbers where the number itself is equal to the sum of its digits raised to the power of the number of its digits.

Example:

- `153  = 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3`
  ...so, 153 *is* Armstrong Number.
- `142 != 1^3 + 4^3 + 2^3`
  ...so, 142 *is not* an Armstrong Number.

Can somebody help me in writing codes for all 3 digits Armstrong number in R?

Comment: `armnum<-c(153,370,371,407); print(armnum)` . To quote wikipedia, "These are odd facts, very suitable for puzzle columns and likely to amuse amateurs, but there is nothing in them which appeals to the mathematician" .

Comment: Sure we can help, but you should show some effort.

Comment: This [solution](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html) in Fortran might help.

Comment: Downvoters, you should give the total newbie OP a chance to update their question! They haven't been seen since the initial post!

Comment: Hi, rough welcome to SO. Since you are new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it and to avoid getting massively downvoted! Please also read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: -1 You didn't seem to heed any advice  and haven't updated your question.

Answer (score 13):

A quick and dirty solution using `?strsplit`:

```r
armstrong <- function(x) {
  tmp <- strsplit(as.character(x), split="")  
  y <- sapply(tmp, function(y)sum(as.numeric(y)^length(y)))
  return(y == x)
}
```

E.g.:

```r
armstrong(c(153, 142))
# [1] TRUE FALSE

# find all 3 digit numbers:
s <- 100:999
s[armstrong(s)]
# [1] 153 370 371 407
# @CarlWitthoft: wikipedia was right ;)
```

Comment: `100:999` instead of `seq`?

Comment: While Armstrong numbers are of little use, this code snippet is a nice example of how to play with the digits of integers.  But I should give you -1 for mipselling "Armstrong" :-)

Answer (score 6):

A variation on a theme...

I have in my R snippets a function from Greg Snow. <s>I'll see if I can dig up a link later.</s> Here's [the original answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/sum-of-digits-or-how-to-slice-a-number-into-its-digits-tp3335192p3335758.html) to a somewhat similar question. It's called "`digits`" and serves to split up a number into digits without using `strsplit`.

```r
digits <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) > 1 ) {
    lapply(x, digits)
  } else {
    n <- ceiling(log10(x))
    x %/% 10^seq(0, length.out=n) %% 10
  }
}
```

Using that function, we can do something like:

```r
A <- 100:999
A[sapply(digits(A), function(y) sum(y^length(y))) == A]
# [1] 153 370 371 407
```

It is, unfortunately, the slowest of the three functions here :(

Comment: +1 for this great example (nearly) without casting to `character`. You could replace `nchar` by `n <- floor(log10(x))+1L` to get rid of the last `as.character` conversion (will be a little bit faster on my machine).

Comment: And for this application you could drop the call to `rev` as well, since you are just cubing and adding the digits, order does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
(a <- rowSums(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(100:999),''))),nrow=900,byrow=TRUE)^3))[a==100:999]
[1] 153 370 371 407
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, was that comment directed towards my answer perhaps? It is definitely the slowest of the three, and I think this one is the fastest. Thomas, there's no need to smash everything on one line. Perhaps that's the memory hog that Carl is referring to! :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto no, I was guessing that Tomas' creation of a gigundo matrix was the biggest RAM-eater.  Your approach just creates a 1-dim list, right?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft OK, I'll use more lines next time. It was not my intention to create best solution (my R knowledge is limited), but rather than that to come up with different approach (good mental exercise on Friday afternoon) :)