# Take mean of digits that are run together in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data is in this format:

```
country gdp digits
US      100 2657
Aus     50  123
NZ      40  11
```

and I'd like to take the mean, for each country of the individual digits that are all stored in the `digits` column.

So this is what I'm after:

```
country gdp digits mean_digits
US      100 2657   5
Aus     50  123    2
NZ      40  11     1
```

I imagine I should split the `digits` column into individual digits in separate columns and then take an arithmetic mean, but I was just a little unsure, because different rows have different numbers of digits in the `digits` field.

Code for the reproducable data below:

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
     country = c("US", "AUS", "NZ"),
         gdp = c(100, 50, 40),
      digits = c(2657, 123, 11)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a function to split the number into digits and take the mean:

```
mean_digits = function(x) {
  sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), split = "", fixed = TRUE),
         function(x) mean(as.integer(x)))
}

df$mean_digits = mean_digits(df$digits)
df
#   country gdp digits mean_digits
# 1      US 100   2657           5
# 2     AUS  50    123           2
# 3      NZ  40     11           1
```

`as.character()` converts the numeric input to `character`, `strsplit` splits the numbers into individual digits (resulting in a `list`), then with `sapply`, to each list element we convert to integer and take the mean.

We use `fixed = TRUE` for a little bit of efficiency, since we don't need any special regex to split every digit apart.

If you're using this function frequently, you may want to `round` or check that the input is integer, it will return `NA` if the input has decimals due to the `.`.

Comment: You explained the code so clearly. I'd be a little lost with the `sapply` without your explanation, so very much appreciated.

Comment: with the second `function(x)` within the `mean_digits` function, is there recursion going on there? I'm trying to work out what the second `function(x)` does. Thank you.

Comment: No recursion. `sapply` only applies a single function to the data. I want to apply 2 functions, first `as.integer`, then `mean`. I could make a function `my_function = function(x) mean(as.integer(x))`, but I'm only going to use it this one time inside `sapply`, so I don't want to go to the bother of naming. So instead I can just pass the unnamed definition of the function, `function(x) mean(as.integer(x))`, which is called an *anonymous function*.

Comment: I used `x` out of habit---it doesn't matter that the `mean_digits` function also called it's argument `x`. I could have used `function(blarg) mean(as.integer(blarg))` just as well

Comment: Another way to think of it: Let's say I have `dd = c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5)` and I want to get the average, removing the `NA`. A lame way to do it is `my_narm_pref = TRUE` and then `mean(dd, na.rm = my_narm_pref)`. That's pointless though, unless I want to re-use that preference in different functions, so I'll just do `mean(dd, na.rm = TRUE) `. This is just the same, except that instead of a simple argument like `TRUE` or `FALSE`, `sapply` takes a function as an argument. I don't want to save and reuse the function, so I pass the function directly without naming it.

Comment: The explanation above is so helpful. Just in case anyone is looking at this question later on, here's a link to an explanation of *anonymous functions*
http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions

Answer (score 2):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(digits = str_split(digits, pattern = "")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 group_by(country, gdp) %>%
 summarise(digits = mean(as.numeric(digits)))

  country   gdp digits
  <chr>   <int>  <dbl>
1 Aus        50      2
2 NZ         40      1
3 US        100      5
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(digits = str_split(digits, pattern = "")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 group_by(country, gdp) %>%
 summarise_all(list(~ mean(as.numeric(.))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `stringr` alternative. It uses `sapply` with `str_extract_all` to extract the characters of `df$digits` for each row and calculates the mean.

```
library(stringr)
df$mean_digits <- sapply(str_extract_all(df$digits, ".{1}"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))

df
  country gdp digits mean_digits
1      US 100   2657           5
2     AUS  50    123           2
3      NZ  40     11           1
```

Or, if you really wanted to, you could do it by using the matrix output from `str_extract_all` and `rowMeans`. Note: for `str_extract_all`, `simplify = FALSE` is the default.

```
extracted_mat <- str_extract_all(df$digits, ".{1}", simplify = TRUE)
class(extracted_mat) <- "numeric"

df$mean_digits <- rowMeans(extracted_mat, na.rm = T)
```

EDIT: running benchmarks on a larger scale (i.e., using @Gregor's sample suggestion).

```
# Packages 
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)

# Functions
mean_digits = function(x) {
  sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), split = "", fixed = TRUE),
         function(x) mean(as.integer(x)))
}
mnDigit <- function(x) {
  n <- nchar(x)
  sq <- as.numeric(paste0("1e", n:0))
  mean((x %% sq[-length(sq)]) %/% sq[-1])
}
mnDigit2 <- function(a) {
  dig <- ceiling(log10(a + 1))
  vec1 <- 10^(dig:1)
  vec2 <- vec1 / 10
  mean((a %% vec1) %/% vec2)
}

# Creating x
set.seed(1)
x = sample(1:1e7, size = 5e5)


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mnDigit2=sapply(x, mnDigit2),
                               mnDigit=sapply(x, mnDigit),
                               stringr=sapply(str_extract_all(x, ".{1}"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x))),
                               stringr_matrix = {
                                 extracted_mat <- str_extract_all(x, ".{1}", simplify = TRUE)
                                 class(extracted_mat) <- "numeric"
                                 rowMeans(extracted_mat, na.rm = T)
                               },
                               strsplit=mean_digits(x),
                               rowMeans=rowMeans(read.table(text = gsub("\\b", " ", x), fill = NA), na.rm = TRUE),
                               #strapply=sapply(strapply(x, ".", as.numeric, simplify=TRUE), mean),
                               times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
       mnDigit2 3154.4249 3226.633 3461.847 3445.867 3612.690 3840.691    10   c 
        mnDigit 6403.7460 6613.345 6876.223 6736.304 6965.453 7634.197    10    d
        stringr 3277.0188 3628.581 3765.786 3711.022 3808.547 4347.229    10   c 
 stringr_matrix  944.5599 1029.527 1136.334 1090.186 1169.633 1540.976    10 a   
       strsplit 3087.6628 3259.925 3500.780 3416.607 3585.573 4249.027    10   c 
       rowMeans 1354.5196 1449.871 1604.305 1594.297 1745.088 1828.070    10  b 



identical(sapply(x, mnDigit2), sapply(x, mnDigit))
[1] TRUE
identical(sapply(x, mnDigit2), sapply(str_extract_all(x, ".{1}"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x))))
[1] TRUE
identical(sapply(x, mnDigit2), {
  extracted_mat <- str_extract_all(x, ".{1}", simplify = TRUE)
  class(extracted_mat) <- "numeric"
  rowMeans(extracted_mat, na.rm = T)
})
[1] TRUE
identical(sapply(x, mnDigit2), mean_digits(x))
[1] TRUE
identical(sapply(x, mnDigit2), rowMeans(read.table(text = gsub("\\b", " ", x), fill = NA), na.rm = TRUE))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

An another `tidyverse` one-liner w/o other dependencies:

```
df %>% mutate(mean_digits =  map_dbl(strsplit(as.character(df$digits), ""), 
                                     ~ mean(as.numeric(.x))))
#   country gdp digits mean_digits
# 1      US 100   2657           5
# 2     AUS  50    123           2
# 3      NZ  40     11           1
```

### Explanation

1. You use `strsplit` to split the digits into single digits. This gives you a list where each element contains the single digits.
2. Then you loop over this list and calculate the `mean` over these digits. Here we use `map_dbl` from `purrr` but a simple `sapply` would also do the trick.

---

Or a solution based on arithmetics rather than string spliiting:

```
df %>% mutate(mean_digits = 
                map_dbl(digits, 
                        ~ mean((.x %/% 10 ^ (0:(nchar(as.character(.x)) - 1)) %% 10))))
```

### Explanation

You integer divide (`%/%`) each number by powers of 10  (i.e. `10^0`, `10^1`, `10^2`, `...`, `10^i` up to the number of digits and you take this result modulo `10` (which gives you exactly the original digit). Then you calculate the mean.

---

### Bare functions to be used for benchmarking

```
split_based <- function(x) {
   sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ""), 
            function(.x) mean(as.numeric(.x)))
}

## split_based(df$digits)

arithmetic_based <- function(.x) {
   mean((.x %/% 10 ^ (0:(nchar(as.character(.x)) - 1)) %% 10))
}

## sapply(df$digits, arithmetic_based)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might more efficiently be done with aritmetics.

Inspired from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765843/6574038) we could do:

```
mnDigit <- function(x) {
  n <- nchar(x)
  sq <- as.numeric(paste0("1e", n:0))
  mean((x %% sq[-length(sq)]) %/% sq[-1])
}

sapply(df$digits, mnDigit)
# [1] 5 2 1
```

*Explanation:* In the function `nchar` first counts the digits and creates a vector of powers of `10`. The final line basically counts each power of `10` in modulo.

Applying the "more general solution" mentioned in the linked answer would look like this (thx to *@thothal* for fixing the error):

```
mnDigit2 <- function(a) {
  dig <- ceiling(log10(a + 1))
  vec1 <- 10^(dig:1)
  vec2 <- vec1 / 10
  mean((a %% vec1) %/% vec2)
}
```

Let's take a look at the benchmark:

```
  Unit: milliseconds
            expr        min         lq      mean    median         uq         max neval cld
mnDigit2          140.65468  152.48952  173.7740  171.3010  179.23491   248.25977    10  a 
mnDigit           130.21340  151.76850  185.0632  166.7446  193.03661   292.59642    10  a 
stringr           112.80276  116.17671  129.7033  130.6521  137.24450   149.82282    10  a 
strsplit          106.64857  133.76875  155.3771  138.6853  148.58234   257.20670    10  a 
rowMeans           27.58122   28.55431   37.8117   29.5755   41.82507    66.96972    10  a 
strapply         6260.85467 6725.88120 7673.3511 6888.5765 8957.92438 10773.54486    10   b
split_based       363.59171  432.15120  475.5603  459.9434  528.20592   623.79144    10  a 
arithmetic_based  137.60552  172.90697  195.4316  183.1395  208.44365   292.07671    10  a
```

<sub>*Note:* I've taken out the `tidyverse` solutions because they are too nested with additional data frame manipulation.</sub>

However, this seems **NOT** to be true. In fact the `rowMeans` - `read.table` approach seems to be by far the fastest.

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("US", "AUS", "NZ"), gdp = c(100, 50, 
40), digits = c(2657, 123, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

***Benchmark code***

```
set.seed(42)
evav <- sample(1:1e5, size=1e4)

library(stringr)  # for str_extract_all
library(gsubfn)  # for strapply
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mnDigit2=sapply(evav, mnDigit2),
                               mnDigit=sapply(evav, mnDigit2),
                               stringr=sapply(str_extract_all(evav, ".{1}"), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x))),
                               strsplit=mean_digits(evav),
                               rowMeans=rowMeans(read.table(text = gsub("\\b", " ", evav), fill = NA), na.rm = TRUE),
                               strapply=sapply(strapply(evav, ".", as.numeric, simplify=TRUE), mean),
                               split_based=sapply(evav, split_based),
                               arithmetic_based=sapply(evav, arithmetic_based),
                               times=10L,
                               control=list(warmup=10L))
# see `mean_digits` `split_based` & `arithmetic_based` functions in other answers
```

Comment: Well, your function does not give the correct results: `mnDigit(1000) #0` but should be `0.25`

Comment: @thothal Interesting, rolled back to first version which works.

Comment: Thanks for including the benchmark. I think it is really helpful!! However, wouldn't it be wise to scale up `df$digits` for benchmarking (opposed to n=3)? And, if benchmarking, I think the `stringr`_matrix solution is probably quicker.

Comment: @jay.sf issue was that `ceiling(log10(1000)) ` is exactly `3`. Easy solution is to use `ceiling(log10(a + 1))`.

Comment: @thothal thanks, I'll rewrite the function. And already taken account for the tidyverses.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Done so, any more suggestions?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Added benchmark of a fresh R session, also taken your update into account which performs a little better.

Comment: If I copy and paste that into a fresh session I get: Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'mnDigit2' not found

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but you can find `mnDigit2` in my answer.

Comment: I was after something that is complete and self contained so it can be easily reproduced.

Comment: (a) My `mean_digits` function uses `sapply` internally, you don't need to wrap it in `sapply`, that just slows it down. (b) If you're gonna bother to run a benchmark, better to do it 10 times on input of size 500k - 1M (input big enough for timing to matter) rather than 100 times on input of length 3. I'd recommend re-running on input such as `x = sample(1:1e7, size = 5e5)`

Comment: @Gregor Done so. However, that nobody has to wait 7 years for the benchmark, we are satisfied with a little less numbers :) The results are indeed amazingly different. Thanks all for this discussion.

Comment: Yes, microbenchmark is nice enough to give LQ and UQ (and min and max) to estimate the spread as well, so running 100 times is almost never needed---even 5 times is usually plenty to tell any difference that matters. I do question your `rowMeans` numbers, Andrew beat you to an updated benchmark and their `rowMeans` placed in a respectable 2nd, not a runaway first.

Comment: @Gregor I can replicate the 1st place though (`all.equal` yields `TRUE`), probably machine dependent? However there may be slightly different results on a "clean" machine running nothing but OS and R.

Answer (score 2):

**1) strapply** This one-liner uses `strapply` in gsubfn.  It converts each digit to numeric and then takes the mean of each.

```
library(gsubfn)

transform(df, mean = sapply(strapply(digits, ".", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE), mean))
```

**2)** This is a little longer but still one statement and uses no packages.  It inserts a space between digits, reads them using `read.table` and then applies `rowMeans`.

```
transform(df, 
  mean = rowMeans(read.table(text = gsub("\\b", " ", digits), fill = NA), na.rm = TRUE))
```