# Measuring function execution time in R

Tags: r, time, profiling

Is there a standardized way in R of measuring execution time of function?

Obviously I can take `system.time` before and after execution and then take the difference of those, but I would like to know if there is some standardized way or function (would like to not invent the wheel).

---

I seem to remember that I have once used something like below:

```
somesysfunction("myfunction(with,arguments)")
> Start time : 2001-01-01 00:00:00  # output of somesysfunction
> "Result" "of" "myfunction"        # output of myfunction
> End time : 2001-01-01 00:00:10    # output of somesysfunction
> Total Execution time : 10 seconds # output of somesysfunction
```

Comment: I think you had `proc.time` on mind cause `system.time` is one you need.

Comment: For larger functions, `Rprof` is nice.  It provides a profile of all the processes in a code chunk/function.

Comment: New R users finding this question through google: `require(microbenchmark)` is now (since a couple years ago) the community standard way to time things. `times <- microbenchmark( lm(y~x), glm(y~x), times=1e3); example(microbenchmark)`. This does a _statistical_ comparison of `lm` vs `glm` over 1000 tries, rather than `system.time` testing only once.

Comment: use `res <- microbenchmark(your code1,your code2)` and then `print(res)` to see a table or `ggplot2::autoplot(res)` to see a boxplot! [ref](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/microbenchmark.pdf)

Answer (score 323):

Another possible way of doing this would be to use Sys.time():

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
...Relevent codes...
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Not the most elegant way to do it, compared to the answere above , but definitely a way to do it.

Comment: This is much more memory-efficient, then system.time(), which effectively copies its arguments. It is important when you are dealing with data that barely fit into your RAM.

Comment: For people who use `Sys.time`, please read this for some caveat: [Timing R code with Sys.time()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51237158/4891738)

Comment: `system.time()` was faster for me. I think that answer for `system.time()` should be accepted!

Comment: This is my preferred way to know the time it takes for a long calculation done in parallel on multiple cores. In this case, the wall clock time measured through this call is accurate enough since the computer will be much busier with all cores calculating than doing anything else and the calculations take minutes or hours to complete. This is a very specific use case but worth mentioning.

Comment: For those that like one-liners: `s=Sys.time(); <code here> ; Sys.time()-s;`. This will print the time difference, along with any output your code might produce.

Answer (score 219):

The built-in function `system.time()` will do it.

Use like: `system.time(result <- myfunction(with, arguments))`

Comment: Important to know is that `system.time()` has an argument `gcFirst` which is `TRUE` by default. This on the one hand makes the measuring a bit more reproducible but can generate a significant overhead of total run time (which is not measured, off course).

Comment: what unit is this measured in? for example I just ran `system.time(result <- myfunction(with, arguments))` and got 187.564 as an output- is that in seconds or what?

Comment: For people who use `system.time`, please read this for some caveat: [“object not found” and “unexpected symbol” errors when timing R code with system.time()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51536556/4891738).

Comment: @zsad512 I am reasonable sure that those are [seconds](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/proc.time).

Answer (score 64):

As Andrie said, `system.time()` works fine. For short function I prefer to put `replicate()` in it:

```
system.time( replicate(10000, myfunction(with,arguments) ) )
```

Comment: You are better of using the microbenchmark package because it doesn't include the overhead of replicate in the timing.

Answer (score 56):

`microbenchmark` is a lightweight (~50kB) package and more-or-less a standard way in R for benchmarking multiple expressions and functions:

```
microbenchmark(myfunction(with,arguments))
```

For example:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(log10(5), log(5)/log(10), times = 10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
           expr min lq    mean median uq   max neval cld
       log10(5)   0  0 25.5738      0  1 10265 10000   a
 log(5)/log(10)   0  0 28.1838      0  1 10265 10000
```

Here both the expressions were evaluated 10000 times, with mean execution time being around 25-30 ns.

Answer (score 41):

A slightly nicer way of measuring execution time, is to use the [rbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbenchmark/) package. This package (easily) allows you to specify how many times to replicate your test and would the relative benchmark should be.

See also a related question at [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3235/timing-functions-in-r)

Comment: Microbenchmark is even better because it uses higher precision timing functions.

Comment: @hadley But rbenchmark is more user-friendly in case of comparisons. For me microbenchmark is upgraded system.time. rmicrobenchmark is what we need :)

Comment: The maintainer of microbenchmark is pretty responsive - I bet he'd add whatever you needed.

Answer (score 41):

There is also `proc.time()`

You can use in the same way as `Sys.time` but it gives you a similar result to `system.time`.

```
ptm <- proc.time()
#your function here
proc.time() - ptm
```

the main difference between using

```
system.time({ #your function here })
```

is that the `proc.time()` method still does execute your function instead of just measuring the time...
and by the way, I like to use `system.time` with `{}` inside so you can put a set of things...

Answer (score 33):

The package "tictoc" gives you a very simple way of measuring execution time. The documentation is in: https://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/tictoc/tictoc.pdf.

```
install.packages("tictoc")
require(tictoc)
tic()
rnorm(1000,0,1)
toc()
```

To save the elapsed time into a variable you can do:

```
install.packages("tictoc")
require(tictoc)
tic()
rnorm(1000,0,1)
exectime <- toc()
exectime <- exectime$toc - exectime$tic
```

Answer (score 22):

Although other solutions are useful for a single function, I recommend the following piece of code where is more general and effective:

```
Rprof(tf <- "log.log", memory.profiling = TRUE)
# the code you want to profile must be in between
Rprof (NULL) ; print(summaryRprof(tf))
```

Comment: I didn't know about Rprof until now and it's indeed great! plus it comes with base R so no need for extra package as `microbenchmark` or `profvis`.

Comment: I wonder if rprof can be visualize as well, like for example if we want to plot the time for each items it profiling?

Comment: @ZawirAmin There is a way, just use Rstudio >> profile menu

Answer (score 15):

Another simple but very powerful way to do this is by using the package `profvis`. It doesn't just measure the execution time of your code but gives you a drill down for each function you execute. It can be used for Shiny as well.

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
  #your code here
})
```

Click [here](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/examples.html) for some examples.

Answer (score 14):

You can use MATLAB-style `tic`-`toc` functions, if you prefer.  See this other SO question

[Stopwatch function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716012/stopwatch-function-in-r/1716344#1716344)

Comment: Was about to add `proc.time()` … I like the cute name better. =)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Sys.time()`. However, when you record the time difference in a table or a csv file, you cannot simply say `end - start`. Instead, you should define the unit:

```
f_name <- function (args*){
start <- Sys.time()
""" You codes here """
end <- Sys.time()
total_time <- as.numeric (end - start, units = "mins") # or secs ... 
}
```

Then you can use `total_time` which has a proper format.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [bench package website](https://bench.r-lib.org/#features):

> `bench::mark()` from package `bench` is used to benchmark one or a series of expressions, we feel it has a number of advantages over alternatives.
>
> - Always uses the highest precision APIs available for each operating system (often nanoseconds).
> - Tracks memory allocations for each expression.
> - Tracks the number and type of R garbage collections per expression iteration.
> - Verifies equality of expression results by default, to avoid accidentally benchmarking inequivalent code.
> - Has `bench::press()`, which allows you to easily perform and combine benchmarks across a large grid of values.
> - Uses adaptive stopping by default, running each expression for a set amount of time rather than for a specific number of iterations.
> - Expressions are run in batches and summary statistics are calculated after filtering out iterations with garbage collections. This allows you to isolate the performance and effects of garbage collection on running time (for more details see Neal 2014).
>
> The times and memory usage are returned as custom objects which have human readable formatting for display (e.g. 104ns) and comparisons (e.g. x$mem_alloc > "10MB").
>
> There is also full support for plotting with ggplot2 including custom scales and formatting.

Use:

```r
bench::mark(log10(5))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 log10(5)      212ns    274ns  2334086.        0B        0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Compiling from all anwsers above I came up to use these simplified tic toc functions

```
tic <- function(){ start.time <<- Sys.time() }
toc <- function(){ round(Sys.time() - start.time) }
```

to be used as:

```
tic()
Sys.sleep(3)
toc()
```

and which prints:

> Time difference of 3 secs

Answer (score 2):

Several answers mention taking the difference of two `Sys.time()`s, ie.

```
start <- Sys.time()
## ... code here ... ##
end <- Sys.time()
end - start
```

This prints the result in human-readable format, such as "time difference of 2 secs". However, since the unit can vary (from "secs" to "mins" to "days"), it is less useful, say, to compare multiple runtimes on equal footing with this method if their units differ.

For **non-interactive** purposes, it is preferred to specify the unit of time.

Specifically, `Sys.time()` returns a `POSIXct` object. Taking the difference of two `POSIXct`s give an object of class `difftime`, which has a "units" attribute. The `` `-` `` operation, in particular, is defined to use `difftime()` when used with a `POSIXct`. That is,

```
time2 - time1
```

is equivalent to

```
difftime(time2, time1)
```

To specify the units attribute, add a `units=` argument, eg.

```
difftime(time2, time1, units="secs")
```

**In summary**, one can use `Sys.time()` measure runtimes with a *specified unit* (secs, mins, etc.), ie.

```
start <- Sys.time()
## ... code here ... ##
end <- Sys.time()
difftime(end, start, units="secs")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(rbenchmark)

sleep_func <- function() { Sys.sleep(0.5) }

benchmark(sleep_func())
```

out:

```
 test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child

1 sleep_func()          100   50.08        1      0.02        0         NA        NA
```