# How can I measure the performance of my code?

Tags: r, performance, profiling

For example, I want to know the time it took to finish and the computing power. The idea of knowing these things exactly is so that it can help me choose between different computing methods that have the same task.

Comment: see `?system.time` and perhaps package `microbenchmark` for timing details: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/microbenchmark/index.html

Comment: Add `Rprof` to that list if you're examining a function or a longer code chunk.  `tracemem` for copying

Comment: and this post seems relevant re: memory usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856306/monitor-memory-usage-in-r

Comment: ...and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3650862/324364) and the performant code section of [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/).

Answer (score 1):

Time to finish is easy:

[get execution time in milliseconds in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546946/get-execution-time-in-milliseconds-in-r)

Get system time at the start and end of your code and calculate the different.

"Computing power" is harder.  CPU?  Memory?  Disk I/O?  What's the criterion for deciding?