# switch() statement usage

Tags: r, switch-statement

I am a little confused about the switch statement in R. 
Simply googling the function I get an example as follows:

A common use of switch is to branch according to the character value of one of the arguments to a function.

```
 > centre <- function(x, type) {
 + switch(type,
 +        mean = mean(x),
 +        median = median(x),
 +        trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
 + }
 > x <- rcauchy(10)
 > centre(x, "mean")
 [1] 0.8760325
 > centre(x, "median")
 [1] 0.5360891
 > centre(x, "trimmed")
 [1] 0.6086504
```

However this just seems to be the same as just having a bunch of `if` statements designated for each `type`

Is that all there is to `switch()`? Can someone give me further examples and better applications?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Well, timing to the rescue again. It seems `switch` is generally faster than `if` statements.
So that, and the fact that the code is shorter/neater with a `switch` statement leans in favor of `switch`:

```
# Simplified to only measure the overhead of switch vs if

test1 <- function(type) {
 switch(type,
        mean = 1,
        median = 2,
        trimmed = 3)
}

test2 <- function(type) {
 if (type == "mean") 1
 else if (type == "median") 2
 else if (type == "trimmed") 3
}

system.time( for(i in 1:1e6) test1('mean') ) # 0.89 secs
system.time( for(i in 1:1e6) test2('mean') ) # 1.13 secs
system.time( for(i in 1:1e6) test1('trimmed') ) # 0.89 secs
system.time( for(i in 1:1e6) test2('trimmed') ) # 2.28 secs
```

**Update** With Joshua's comment in mind, I tried other ways to benchmark. The microbenchmark seems the best. ...and it shows similar timings:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(test1('mean'), test2('mean'), times=1e6)
Unit: nanoseconds
           expr  min   lq median   uq      max
1 test1("mean")  709  771    864  951 16122411
2 test2("mean") 1007 1073   1147 1223  8012202

> microbenchmark(test1('trimmed'), test2('trimmed'), times=1e6)
Unit: nanoseconds
              expr  min   lq median   uq      max
1 test1("trimmed")  733  792    843  944 60440833
2 test2("trimmed") 2022 2133   2203 2309 60814430
```

**Final Update** Here's showing how versatile `switch` is:

```
switch(type, case1=1, case2=, case3=2.5, 99)
```

This maps `case2` and `case3` to `2.5` and the (unnamed) default to `99`. For more information, try `?switch`

Comment: Using a for loop like that can cause issues with garbage collection.  The difference is much smaller with a better benchmarking function: `benchmark(test1('trimmed'), test2('trimmed'), replications=1e6)`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich ...which `benchmark` function are you using? Not the obvious one from the "benchmark" package it seems?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/function-in-r-to-measure-function-execution-time/6262540#6262540 "microbenchmark" is an even better one.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I updated the answer with results from `microbencmark`, but they are very similar to my original ones. I don't really see how rbenchmark would get around the GC issue, but it seems to have more overhead by calling `eval` and `replicate`.

Comment: just as am aside can I have multiple cases with the same output? i.e. `switch(type, c(this,that)=do something)`

Comment: @Ellipsis... Yes, `switch(type, case1=1, case2=, case3=2.5, 99)` maps `case2` and `case3` to 2.5 and the (unnamed) default to `99`.

Answer (score 4):

In short, **yes**. But there are times when you might favor one vs. the other. Google "case switch vs. if else". There are some discussions already on SO too. Also, here is a good video that talks about it in the context of MATLAB:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/01/02/matlab-basics-switch-case-vs-if-elseif/

Personally, when I have 3 or more cases, I usually just go with case/switch.

Answer (score 1):

Switch can also be much easier to read than a series of if() statements. How about:

```
switch(id,
   "edit" = {
      CODEBLOCK
   },
   "delete" = {
      CODEBLOCK
   },
   stop(paste0("No handler for ", id))
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `switch` and `if-else` is mainly a stylistic choice. In general, the language-independent ([c++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98024/14853907), [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395965/14853907)) rule-of-thumb is to use `switch` when there are roughly 3-5 or more conditions to improve code readability. That said, there are some differences between `switch` and `if` in R that make it more than *branching thingie*.

---

**Character input**
> *Most often used*
> *Example case:* small dictionary.
`f <- function(x) switch(x, a = 100, b = 200, c = 300, 0)`
`g <- function(x) if(x == "a") 100 else if(x == "b") 200 else if(x == "c") 300 else 0`
You can supply the `Expr` argument as a regular strings, in backticks or as names, or empty value. An empty element is *falling through*, meaning that the next will be evaluated. If no match is found, the default is returned.

```
chr_switch <- function(expr) {
    switch(
        expr,
        "a" = 1,
        b =,
        `c` = 3,
        4
    )
}

sapply(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), chr_switch)
#> a b c d 
#> 1 3 3 4
```

**Numeric input**
> *Not used as often*
> *Example case 1:* if *n* arguments are given, do that expression
`f <- function(...) switch(...length(), 100, 200, 300)`
`g <- function(...) {l = ...length(); if(l == 1) 100 else if(l == 2) 200 else 300}`

```
num_switch <- function(expr) switch(expr, "one","two","three","four")
sapply(1:3, num_switch)
#> [1] "one"   "two"   "three"

num_switch_empty <- function(expr) switch(expr, "one",,"three","four")
sapply(c(1, 3), num_switch_empty) # works. Note the numeric, not an integer!
#> [1] "one"   "three"
sapply(c(1,2,3), num_switch_empty) # error because 2 is empty
```

From the example above we see that type coercion takes place (numeric & integer). This coercion is not identical to `as.integer`, see `switch(as.raw(1), 100)`. `if` does not coerce. Consider a factor,

```
fct <- as.factor(c("a", "b"))
switch(fct[1], "one", "two") # one + warning
switch(fct[2], "one", "two") # two + warning
if(fct[1]) "one" else "two" # one
if(fct[2]) "one" else "two" # one
```

### Performance

A benchmark<sup>1</sup> for increasing `n` number of nested expressions. `switch` outperforms nested `if` quite early on, but overall the performance difference is negligible, even if you somehow write 150 (!) nested if calls. Note that these are for single calls, not for vectors of inputs. The vectorized version of `if` is `ifelse`. [vectorized switch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31156957/14853907) is implement in the [kit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kit/kit.pdf#page=%5B17%5D) package.

```
make_if <- Vectorize(function(x) {
    paste(paste0(rep("if(TRUE)", x), collapse = " "), "1L")
})
make_if(10)
#> "if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) if(TRUE) 1L"
make_switch <- Vectorize(function(x) {
    paste0("switch(", x, paste0(replicate(x, ","), collapse = ""), 1L, ")")
})
make_switch(10) 
[1] "switch(10,,,,,,,,,,1)"
```

transforming into expressions, and calling `bench::mark(iterations = 1e4)` gives
[image]

<sup>1</sup>   don't bet your life on sub-second bench marks