# If else building block

Tags: r, if-statement

Is there an equivalent building block in R for

```
if ($a > $b) {
    echo "a is bigger than b";
} elseif ($a == $b) {
    echo "a is equal to b";
} else {
    echo "a is smaller than b";
}
```

from PHP or Java?

Comment: Maybe [this][1] "switch" can help you?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393508/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-r-functions

Comment: For the people who know R but not PHP or Java perhaps describe what `echo` does.  Maybe also add the result you want to your post.  Maybe also add the PHP and Java tags to your post.

Comment: `else if` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not idiomatic but the answer is yes:

```
if (a > b) {
  cat("a is bigger than b")
} else if (a == b) {
  cat("a is equal to b")
} else {
  cat("a is smaller than b")
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth explaining that this is not idiomatic because it is not vectorised.  The `ifelse` function is a vectorised alternative.  Also, I'd be tempted by `message` rather than `cat` (which is low level and not really meant to be called directly).

Comment: Also worth explaining that the curly braces (my edit) are necessary to avoid the possibility that R reads the first two lines as a complete statement then throw `Error: unexpected ’else’ in "else"`.

Comment: @Richie ```message``` is probably to be recommended but I suppose ```cat``` is arguably closer to ```echo```.

Comment: @flodel That is a good correction. The other option is to put the ```else``` before the line break. Although all work (including the original) if it is defined within a function.