# R switch / case with advanced conditions

Tags: r, switch-statement

I have a series of nested `if..else` statements that I would like to replace with a case statement. Now R has a simple switch operator such as the following:

```
switch (i) {

    case 1:
        // action 1
        break;
    case 2:
        // action 2
        break;
    case 3:
        // action 3
        break;
    default:
        // action 4
        break;
}
```

However, my cases are more complicated conditionals, not simple literal values.

I need something like

```
switch {

    case i %in% someList:
        // action 1
        break;
    case i %in% someOtherList:
        // action 2
        break;
    case i > 42:
        // action 3
        break;
    default:
        // action 4
        break;
}
```

Does anyone know if something like this is possible in R? It would make the code I am working on much simpler to read.

As far as I can see, this question is *not* answered here: [How to use the switch statement in R functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393508/how-to-use-the-switch-statement-in-r-functions)

Thanks

Comment: Is this a duplicate? OP asks for specific `switch` cases that can't be mapped to `switch` parameters

Comment: Wouldnt this be a use case for simple `if` .. `else if` ... statements?

Comment: @docendodiscimus of course that works well enough, and is what I am applying at the moment. But at a certain depth the nesting becomes quite difficult to read (not to mention maintain). A case statement would be a much more elegant solution

Comment: Then you might need to preprocess your conditions so that you can use a switch

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but you can try with nested `ifelse` functions:

```
ifelse(i %in% someList, action1,
       ifelse(i %in% someOtherList, action2,
              ifelse(i > 42, action 3, default_action4)))
```

Comment: That is more or less what I am doing at the moment. Gets quite messy quite quickly!

Comment: @Karl You are right, although you can omit indenting each `ifelse` so it looks more like a `switch` statement