# How to handle multiple if conditions in a simple way?

Tags: r, if-statement

Say I have multiple if conditions, under which different values are assigned to a variable. For instance:

```
x <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 4)
for(i in length(x)) {
    if(x[i] == 2) {
      x[i] <- 10
    }
    if(x[i] == 4) {
      x[i] <- 12
    }
    ## and there are more similar if conditions 
    ## ......
}
```

In general, I'd like to replace the numbers in this vector with other numbers according to specific conditions. Is there a simpler way to do this without writing such a long loop?

Comment: For 2-3 consecutive `if` statements it is possible to use nested `ifelse`. But in your case you are probably missing something more straightforward like `x[x==2] <- 10` and so on, without any `for` or `if`.

Comment: @tonytonov Unless the desired behavior is to only check and affect the last element of the vector; that's what the example code does.

Comment: One option here would be to use a [switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825501/switch-statement-usage)

Comment: @MatthewLundberg That one is difficult to spot, nice catch. Though I presume this is merely a typo. OP, did you mean `for (i in 1:length(x))`?

Comment: @tonytonov oh yes...this is a typo.. Thank you, I found your solution most suitable for my condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need any `if` statements.  You could create a vector of values you want to change `x` to, then change them all directly with `replace`

```
> x <- rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 4)    
> inds <- sapply(c(2, 4), function(z) which(x == z))
> vals <- c(rep(10, nrow(inds)), rep(12, nrow(inds)))
> replace(x, inds, vals)
##  [1]  1 10  3 12  5  6  7  8  1 10  3 12  5  6  7  8  1 10  3 12  5  6
## [23]  7  8  1 10  3 12  5  6  7  8
```

Comment: This exploits the structure of `x` and will not work correctly if e.g. `x <- c(1, 2, 2)`.

Comment: Thanks @tonytonov.  I completely spaced.  Changed to a different method

Comment: Interesting approach. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

If your `x` is small non-zero integers, make a lookup table as a simple vector:

```
lut=c(10,12,13,55,99,12,12,12,99,1010)
lut[x]
 [1] 10 12 13 55 99 12 12 12 10 12 13 55 99 12 12 12 10 12 13 55 99 12 12 12 10
 [26] 12 13 55 99 12 12 12
```

For other keys, use a list and characterify all the things:

```
> lut = list("999"=1, "8"=2, "foo"=223)
> unlist(lut[c("999","999","8","8","8","foo")])
 999 999   8   8   8 foo 
   1   1   2   2   2 223
```