# Use of switch() in R to replace vector values

Tags: r, string, replace, switch-statement

This should be pretty simple but even after checking all documentation and on-line examples I don't get it.

I'd like to use switch() to replace the values of a character vector.

A fake, extremely simple, reproducible example:

```
test<-c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is")
```

Let's say I want to assign "1" to sentences including the verb "to be" and "2" to sentences including the verb "to have". The following DOES NOT work:

```
test<-switch(test,
                "He is"=1,
                "She is"=1,
                "He has"=2,
                "She has"=2)
```

Error message:

```
+ + + + Error in switch(test, `He is` = 1, `She is` = 1, `He has` = 2, `She has` = 2) : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

I think EXPR is indeed a length 1 vector, so what's wrong?

I thought maybe R expected characters as replacements, but neither wrapping switch() into an "as.integer" nor the following work:

```
test<-switch(test,
                "He is"="1",
                "She is"="1",
                "He has"="2",
                "She has"="2")
```

Maybe it doesn't vectorize, and I should make a loop? Is that it? Would be disappointing, considering the strength of R is vectorization. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Vector "test" is of length 4. It cannot work. See with `test <- "He is"`.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this`code <- c("He is"=1, "She is"=1, "He has"=2, "She has"=2); code[test]`?

Comment: Wow @ExperimenteR, that is elegant... I didn't know that if I select objects of a numeric vector with a names attribute using a character, R would use the names attribute to match the numbers of the numeric vector to my character vector. This is my favourite solution, but I cannot choose it as the answer because the question was how to use switch() correctly. Thumbs up tho

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The vectorised form of `if` is `ifelse`:

```
test <- ifelse(test == "He is", 1,
        ifelse(test == "She is", 1,
        ifelse(test == "He has", 2,
        2)))
```

or

```
test <- ifelse(test %in% c("He is", "She is"), 1, 2)
```

`switch` is basically a way of writing nested `if`-`else` tests. You should think of `if` and `switch` as *control flow* statements, not as data transformation operators. You use them to control the execution of an algorithm, eg to test for convergence or to choose which execution path to take. You wouldn't use them to directly manipulate data in most circumstances.

Answer (score 32):

Here is the correct way to *vectorize* a function, e.g. **switch**:

```
# Data vector:
test <- c("He is",
          "She has",
          "He has",
          "She is")

# Vectorized SWITCH:
foo <- Vectorize(vectorize.args = "a",
                 FUN = function(a) {
                   switch(as.character(a),
                          "He is" = 1,
                          "She is" = 1,
                          "He has" = 2,
                          2)})

# Result:
foo(a = test)

  He is She has  He has  She is 
      1       2       2       1
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 24):

You coud try

```
test_out <- sapply(seq_along(test), function(x) switch(test[x],
  "He is"=1,
  "She is"=1,
  "He has"=2,
  "She has"=2))
```

Or equivalently

```
test_out <- sapply(test, switch,
  "He is"=1,
  "She is"=1,
  "He has"=2,
  "She has"=2)
```

Comment: This appears to be the solution, thanks, actually in an even simpler form in which "test" is the object of sapply

Comment: Sorry, another answer included a broad explanation of the notions  behind the problem. But I promise I'll upvote you as soon as my Reputation allows it in a few weeks.

Answer (score 15):

I found this approach the most readable:

```
# input
test <-c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is", "Unknown", "She is")

# mapping
map <- c(
  "He is" = 1, 
  "She has" = 2, 
  "He has" = 2, 
  "She is" = 1)

answer <- map[test]

# output
answer
He is She has  He has  She is    <NA>  She is 
    1       2       2       1      NA       1
```

If `test` is numeric, must convert value to `character` to use this.

Answer (score 4):

While I usually prefer base R approaches, there is a package with a vectorized switch function.

```
library(broman)

switchv(c("horse", "fish", "cat", "bug"),
horse="fast",
cat="cute",
"what?")
```

Added based on comment to use OP data.

```
library(broman)

test<-c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is")


test<-switchv(test,
                "He is"="1",
                "She is"="1",
                "He has"="2",
                "She has"="2")

test
```

Answer (score 2):

"Vectorize" is based on the "mapply" function, whereas "ifelse" is a base function which should be already vectorized. So in terms of performance "Vectorize" might be slower.
It is easy to vectorize an R function with the 'apply' family, but performance is usually an issue on large volumes. Better to use base functions optimized to work with vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `recode()` from `car`:

```
# Data vector:
x <- c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is")

library("car")
recode(x, "'He is'=1; 'She is'=1; 'He has'=2; 'She has'=2") # or
recode(x, "c('He is', 'She is')=1; c('He has', 'She has')=2")
```

Comment: Just to mention here: `recode` is in the `dplyr` package, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a named vector and simple base subsetting methods. E.g.

```r
test <- c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is")

named_vec <- c(
  "He is" = 1,
  "She is" = 1,
  "He has" = 2,
  "She has" = 2
)

named_vec[test]
#>   He is She has  He has  She is 
#>       1       2       2       1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

Package `kit` on CRAN has a vectorised switch function written in C called `vswitch`. You might also be interested to know that it has a nested if function called `nif` and a fast `ifelse` function called `iif`. Please look at the documentation, these functions are really fast compare to base R.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
vSwitch <- function(vExpr,...) {
  l <- list(...)
  if(names(l)[[length(l)]] != '') stop('Last item in match list must be unnamed')
  i <- 0
  recurse <- function(v) {
    i <<- i + 1
    if(names(l[i+1]) != "") {
      ifelse(v == names(l)[[i]],l[[i]], recurse(v))
    } else {
      ifelse(v == names(l)[[i]],l[[i]], l[[i+1]])
    }
  } 
  recurse(vExpr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fancy and tidy way to do it with `purrr` package is like that:

```
purrr::map_int(c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She had", "She is", NA),
    ~ purrr::when(.,
         .x %in% c("He is", "She is") ~ 1L,
         .x %in% c("He has", "She has") ~ 2L,
         ~ NA))
```

Here, `purrr::map()` iterates over the first argument and returns whatever values the second parameter returns. That second parameter is a function, where `purrr` allows to write it in a much less elaborate manner: rather than writing `function(x) x`, one can write simply `~ .`, `~ .x` or `~ .1` (the last working for unlimited number of variables).

Then, we've got `purrr::when()`, which takes a single value and functions as a series of `ifelse` statements. These statements take form of `LHS ~ RHS`. LHS should be a logical expression, it can also use the same way of referencing variables as above; RHS is the value associated with this condition. Value returned is the first that fits. When LHS is empty (as in the last line), then it's treated as `else` clause.

`purrr::map_int()` differs from the `purrr::map()` only in that it guarantees returning a vector of integers (there are similar functions for numerics, logicals and strings).

Answer (score 0):

dplyr 1.1.0 introduced [`case_match`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html), which is a vectorized version of `switch`:

```
library(dplyr)

test<-c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is", "not matched")

case_match(
  test,
  "He is" ~ 1,
  "She is" ~ 1,
  "He has" ~ 2,
  "She has" ~ 2,
  .default = 3 # return value if test not matched
)

[1] 1 2 2 1 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Use revalue() function from the plyr package.

```
library(plyr)
test<-c("He is", "She has", "He has", "She is")
test<-revalue(test,
              c("He is"=1,
                "She is"=1,
                "He has"=2,
                "She has"=2))
test
```

Here is the output.

```
[1] "1" "2" "2" "1"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.