# Want to add 10 different types of icons to a leaflet map

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, icons, markers

Look at my R code, here I am able to mark two different types of marker icon but I want to mark for all the 10 values of quakes$mag column with 10 different types of marker icons.

```
 quakes1 <- quakes[1:10,]

leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(quakes1$mag < 4.6,
                   "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
                   "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)

leaflet(data = quakes1) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, icon = leafIcons)
```

I tried to do it with switch statement instead of ifelse, but it is not working with switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ifelse` is a vectorized function that created your vector of icons for `leafIcons`. There are various ways you can vectorize `switch` or alternatives to create your `leafIcons` based on a vector - see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156957/use-of-switch-in-r-to-replace-vector-values/34599177). With `dplyr` you can use `case_when` which might be what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = case_when(
    quakes1$mag <= 4.3 ~ "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png",
    4.3 < quakes1$mag & quakes1$mag <= 5 ~ "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-orange.png",
    quakes1$mag > 5 ~ "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)
```

You can also use `cut` or `findInterval` if you have a numeric vector that you want to assign icons to different ranges.