# R - Calculate computational cost of scripts

Tags: r, algorithm, code-complexity

I have two scripts in R with similar algorithms. I would like to compare them by computational cost. How can I do this calculation?

Thanks.

Raúl

Comment: Wall time, CPU, overall memory would be my guesses.  Measure; don't calculate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/measuring-function-execution-time-in-r).

First way:

```
ptm <- proc.time()
#your function here
proc.time() - ptm
```

Or another way:

```
system.time({ #your function here })
```

Comment: Are you saying that `system.time` doesn't evaluate the expression passed to it? Because that's simply wrong. Or are you just not aware that you can print, e.g., `system.time(print(1:5))`, or assign, e.g., `system.time(x <- 1:5); x` within it?

Comment: @Roland, you`re right, just checked it.

Comment: I mean to measure the computational cost following the big-o notation automatically

Comment: @user3886573 I think this experimental question, which you try get by measuring different times on diff. initial parameters. Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity