# Is it feasible to know how much time it takes for a called function to finish on R?

Tags: r, time

Sometimes, when I decide to process the function, I fear that it takes an infinite amount of time to finish the process, making my working environment occupied for a while (and to make it worse, in some cases disrupting the process by `esc` doesn't work or work only so much later).

So I want to know **in advance** whether a given function will be finished in an endurable time, and approximately how much it is expected to take to finish the function. This is not a question about [*how to measure the time it **took** to complete the function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/measuring-function-execution-time-in-r).

So is it possible to know it approximately in advance?

Comment: Gregor is right that the in the most general case, this in unknowable. But obviously, people writing code _do_ estimate running time prior to committing to a full run. You just have to write your code in a fashion that it is runnable in increments. Test on a small subset of your data; test on only 10-20 iterations instead of 50k and do some rough extrapolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not possible in R or any other language. Whether or not the program will *ever* stop is called the "halting problem", and [it is provably unsolvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).