# Why reassigning new name to dataframe in dplyr makes it faster?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, tidyverse

I was unhappy with the time dplyr and data.table were taking to create a new variable on my data.frame and decide to compare methods.

To my surprise, reassigning the results of dplyr::mutate() to a new data.frame seems to be faster than not doing so.

Why is this happening?

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)


dt <- fread(".... data.csv") #load 200MB datafile

dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)

a <- Sys.time()
dt1[, MONTH := month(as.Date(DATE))]
b <- Sys.time(); datatabletook <- b-a

c <- Sys.time()
dt_dplyr <- dt2 %>%
  mutate(MONTH = month(as.Date(DATE)))
d <- Sys.time(); dplyr_reassign_took <- d - c 

e <- Sys.time()
dt3 %>%
  mutate(MONTH = month(as.Date(DATE)))
f <- Sys.time(); dplyrtook <- f - e

datatabletook        = 17sec
dplyrtook            = 47sec
dplyr_reassign_took  = 17sec
```

Comment: `dt1 <- dt` does not create a new object called `dt1`; it just makes another pointer to `dt`. Try `dt1 <- copy(dt)`.

Comment: @Frank -- edited the question with your suggestion. Same/similar results.

Comment: Ok, interesting/unexpected result. I guess it would be helpful to have it for a reproducible example.

Comment: Perhaps it's not the assignment that's the problem, but the printing to console that take the extra time? Without repro it's a bit of a guessing game. Also, `dt` is a `data.table`, so is there some conversions going on?

Comment: To check if it's the printing, you could wrap in `system.time()` instead of doing the double `Sys.time()` thing.

Comment: @Frank: wrapped in system.time() and they all take 17sec. Do you want to add the answer?
 >>>>
dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)
dt3 <- copy(dt)

system.time(  dt1[, MONTH := month(as.Date(DATEWEATHER))] )

system.time(  dt_dplyr <- dt2 %>% mutate(MONTH = month(as.Date(DATEWEATHER)))   )

system.time(  dt3 %>% mutate(MONTH = month(as.Date(DATEWEATHER))) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways to [benchmark with base R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6262203/):

```
.t0 <- Sys.time()
    ...
.t1 <- Sys.time()
.t1 - t0    

 # or

 system.time({
     ...
 })
```

With the `Sys.time` way, you're sending each line to the console and may see some return value printed for each line, as @Axeman suggested. With `{...}`, there is only one return value (the last result inside the braces) and `system.time` will suppress it from printing.

If the printing is costly enough but is not part of what you want to measure, it can make a difference.

---

There are good reasons to prefer `system.time` over `Sys.time` for benchmarking; from @MattDowle's comment:

> i) it does a gc first excluded from the timing to isolate from random gc's and
>
> ii) it includes `user` and `sys` time as well as `elapsed` wall clock time.
>
> The `Sys.time()` way will be affected by reading your email in Chrome or using Excel while the test runs, the `system.time()` way won't so long as you use the `user` and `sys` parts of the result.

Comment: `system.time({...})` is much better too because i) it does a gc first excluded from the timing to isolate from random gc's and ii) it includes `user` and `sys` time as well as `elapsed` wall clock time.  The `Sys.time()` way will be affected by reading your email in Chrome or using Excel while the test runs,  the `system.time()` way won't so long as you use the `user` and `sys` parts of the result.