# Threshold for using join over merge

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, plyr

My understanding regarding the difference between the `merge()` function (in base R) and the `join()` functions of `plyr` and `dplyr` are that `join()` is faster and more efficient when working with "large" data sets.

Is there some way to determine a threshold to regarding when to use `join()` over `merge()`, without using a heuristic approach?

Comment: if speed is the main concern you'll probably be better off working either with `data.table` or data bases.

Comment: You may want to directly compare execution speed, see for instance this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/measuring-function-execution-time-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you will be hard pressed to find a "hard and fast" rule around when to switch from one function to another. As others have mentioned, there are a set of tools in R to help you measure performance. `object.size` and `system.time` are two such function that look at memory usage and performance time, respectively. One general approach is to measure the two directly over an arbitrarily expanding data set. Below is one attempt at this. We will create a data frame with an 'id' column and a random set of numeric values, allowing the data frame to grow and measuring how it changes. I'll use `inner_join` here as you mentioned `dplyr`. We will measure time as "elapsed" time.

```
library(tidyverse)

setseed(424)

#number of rows in a cycle
growth <- c(100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,5000000)

#empty lists
n <- 1
l1 <- c()
l2 <- c()

#test for inner join in dplyr
for(i in growth){
  x <- data.frame("id" = 1:i, "value" = rnorm(i,0,1))
  y <- data.frame("id" = 1:i, "value" = rnorm(i,0,1))

  test <- inner_join(x,y, by = c('id' = 'id'))
  l1[[n]] <- object.size(test)

  print(system.time(test <- inner_join(x,y, by = c('id' = 'id')))[3])
  l2[[n]] <- system.time(test <- inner_join(x,y, by = c('id' = 'id')))[3]

  n <- n+1

}

#empty lists
n <- 1
l3 <- c()
l4 <- c()

#test for merge
for(i in growth){
  x <- data.frame("id" = 1:i, "value" = rnorm(i,0,1))
  y <- data.frame("id" = 1:i, "value" = rnorm(i,0,1))

  test <- merge(x,y, by = c('id'))
  l3[[n]] <- object.size(test)
  # print(object.size(test))

  print(system.time(test <- merge(x,y, by = c('id')))[3])
  l4[[n]] <- system.time(test <- merge(x,y, by = c('id')))[3]

  n <- n+1

   }

#ploting output (some coercing may happen, so be it)
plot <- bind_rows(data.frame("size_bytes" = l3, "time_sec" = l4, "id" = "merge"), 
                  data.frame("size_bytes" = l1, "time_sec" = l2, "id" = "inner_join"))

plot$size_MB <- plot$size_bytes/1000000

ggplot(plot, aes(x = size_MB, y =time_sec, color = id)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

`merge` seems to perform worse out the gate, but really kicks off around ~20MB. Is this the final word on the matter? No. But such testing can give you a idea of how to choose a function.