# How to create a scatter plot of a really big data

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I have a really big data of size more than 3 gb (only X and Y variables). The data frame `IBD` has 300 million rows. Is there a better and faster way to plot this?

First, I read the dataframe:

```
IBD <- fread("/40/AD/LL_Cohorts_MERGED-IBD.genome", select = c("X", "Y"))
```

and tried to plot, but it's been over 12 hours and I am not getting any output.

```
ggplot(IBD, aes(x=X, y=Y))+ 
  geom_point() + 
  ggtitle("ADGC EOAD") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
```

Comment: Calculate the clusters and use scatter plot for the centroids. Otherwise, I think you will be facing with a big full rectangular without any space. See [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/kmeans).

Comment: I tried with 1/3rd of the data and it gives me what I expect. So If I can plot it, I think it should be fne. I just need to see the outliers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the run time down is to play with smaller datasets and different code to see which would be faster.

Then you can use `system.time()` to see how long something takes and compare:

[Measuring function execution time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262203/measuring-function-execution-time-in-r)

For example:

```
size<-100000
IBD<-data.frame(X=rbeta(n = size,shape1=2,shape2 = 2),Y=rbeta(n = size,shape1=2,shape2 = 2))
```

Using your code on this fake dataset:

```
system.time(
ggplot(IBD, aes(x=X, y=Y))+ geom_point() + ggtitle("ADGC EOAD") + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
)

   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.01
```

Using base `plot` as a comparison point:

```
system.time(
plot(Y~X, data=IBD)
)

   user  system elapsed 
   2.13    2.34    4.56
```

You can see that `plot` takes a lot longer. I realize this isn't a solution to making your code faster, but it is a tool that you can use to figure out what would be faster on such a large dataset.

---

### Edit:

Adding in the methods from comments by @maydin:

```
cluster<-kmeans(x = IBD, centers = 1000)
Clus<-data.frame(cluster$centers)

system.time(
  ggplot(Clus, aes(x=X, y=Y))+ geom_point() + ggtitle("ADGC EOAD") + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1)) + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
)

   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

Comment: Well, kmeans is also going to take time.

Comment: absolutely it is. You can wrap that within  `system.time()` to see if it would take longer or shorter.