# Storing tic toc values in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to store running times in a variable in R. In MATLAB one can do something along the lines:

> tic;
>   ...
>   x=toc;

and then the running time is stored in the variable x. I have tried doing the same thing with the tic() toc() function in R coming from the MATLAB-package without success. Furthermore I can't see how this can be done using the system.time() function of R neither. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716012/stopwatch-function-in-r

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd: I was asking how to store it.

Comment: @StefanHansen: you store it like you store any other variable value... `<-`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the built-in `system.time` function:

```
tm1 <- system.time(
{
  #your code here
})
```

or, alternatively the `benchmark` function from `rbenchmark` package:

```
tm2 <- benchmark(
{
  #your code here
}, replications=1)
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple. Thanks :)

Comment: I prefer using `system.time` function because: 1. It encapsulates the code that I want to time; 2. In-built function, loading libraries like `tictoc`, `rbenchmark` unnecessary.

Answer (score 15):

More similar to `tic` and `toc` and sometimes handier e.g. for status messages in loops:

```
start <- Sys.time ()
do.something ()
Sys.time () - start
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do as it is described in the 'tictoc' package.

```
tic("timer")
1+1
toc(log = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
log.txt <- tic.log(format = TRUE)
tic.clearlog()
```

your output is then stored in log.txt. You can `unlist(log.txt)` and analyse it as a string if you only want the time in seconds.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

The [tictoc](http://jabiru.github.io/tictoc/) package implements this exact functionality, so the timing of sequential or nested timings is stored in a list and for subsequent analysis.

For example, to time each iteration of a loop and analyze the results later, use the `log` functionality.

```
library(tictoc)
tic.clearlog()
for (x in 1:10) {
    # passing x to tic() makes it a label at time of the matching toc() call.
    tic(x)
    Sys.sleep(1)
    # When log = TRUE, toc() pushes the measured timing to a list
    # quiet = TRUE prevents from printing the timing
    toc(log = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
}
```

Fetch the results of `toc()` as formatted text for printing.

```
log.txt <- tic.log(format = TRUE)
```

Extract the list containing measurements in raw format.

```
log.lst <- tic.log(format = FALSE)
```

Since the data is already extracted, clear the tictoc log.

```
tic.clearlog()
```

Convert the list elements to timings. 
Each element of the list has a start (`tic`) and end (`toc`) timestamp.

```
timings <- unlist(lapply(log.lst, function(x) x$toc - x$tic))
```

Compute the average loop time.

```
mean(timings)
# [1] 1.001
```

Print the text output - note that the prefixes are the values of `x`.

```
writeLines(unlist(log.txt))
# 1: 1.002 sec elapsed
# 2: 1 sec elapsed
# 3: 1.002 sec elapsed
# 4: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 5: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 6: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 7: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 8: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 9: 1.001 sec elapsed
# 10: 1 sec elapsed
```

Comment: An imho more elegant conversion of the results into a dataframe could be done using `purrr` with `log.st %>% map_df(~as_data_frame(.x)) %>% mutate(elapsed=toc-tic)`

Comment: Thanks, @HolgerBrandl. A minor correction in the code: `library(tidyverse); log.lst %>% map_df(~as.data.frame(.x)) %>% mutate(elapsed=toc-tic)`